# Multiple [not(contains(id, ...))] in SimpleXML (xPath)

Tags: xpath, simplexml

I need to exclude multiple ids from the XML list and I was wondering how to make the script to work.

I have something like this

> //Réponses[not(contains(Constituent_x0020_ID, "34282,35224,34094"))] **Not working**
>
> //Réponses[not(contains(Constituent_x0020_ID, "34282"))] **Working**

So what's the correct syntax to use if we want to filter multiple ids so my first exemple works ?

**Update**

This

> //Réponses[not(contains(Constituent_x0020_ID, "34282"))][not(contains(Constituent_x0020_ID, "35224"))][not(contains(Constituent_x0020_ID, "34094"))]

Seems to be working but it's kind of .... too long. Any smaller solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a great solution here, but this would be marginally shorter:

```
//Réponses[not(Constituent_x0020_ID[contains(., "34282") or contains(., "35224") or contains(., "34094")])]
```